# Compilation of GRASS 6.4.trunk on Win7

Tags: grass-gis, windows

you may have seen my other posts, at the point now where I am trying to use the landsat plugins in a lower version of GRASS. Markus N noted that the 6.4.2 might be better, since that is not out yet I have given the 6.4 trunk a go.

Has anyone had any success installing plugins on a Win7 machine?

I worked on a few issues, 
the plugin path needs to be specified with forward slashes / not back slashes, and it needs to have no gaps, so at the install of the GRASS version start a new directory near the C:\ drive. That should be clear from the output below;

```
(Wed May 04 17:18:40 2011)                                                      
g.extension -s --verbose extension=i.landsat.acca svnurl=https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons prefix=C:/GRASSPROG/GRASS64SVN/bin
which: wget: unknown command
Using CURL for downloading data.
Fetching <i.landsat.acca> from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    i.landsat.acca\tools.c
A    i.landsat.acca\local_proto.h
A    i.landsat.acca\main.c
A    i.landsat.acca\description.html
A    i.landsat.acca\algorithm.c
A    i.landsat.acca\Makefile
 U   i.landsat.acca
Checked out revision 46175.
Compiling <i.landsat.acca>...
C:/GRASSPROG/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Module.make:25:
warning: overriding commands for target `install'
C:/GRASSPROG/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Rules.make:90: warning:
ignoring old commands for target `install'
gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such
file or directory
make: *** [OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/algorithm.o] Error 1
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
test -d OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32 || mkdir -p OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32
gcc -I/c/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.2svn/include -I/c/OSGeo4W/include -g -O2  -I/c/OSGeo4W/include     -DPACKAGE=\""grassmods"\"  -I/c/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.2svn/include -o OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/algorithm.o -c algorithm.c
rm: cannot remove directory
`C:\\GRASSDATA/UTM55S/9384Hay/.tmp/1920.0/i.landsat.acca':
 Permission denied
(Wed May 04 17:18:51 2011) Command finished (11 sec)
```

---

Still no joy

```
g.extension --verbose extension=i.landsat.toar prefix=C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/bin 
which: wget: unknown command
Using CURL for downloading data.
Fetching <i.landsat.toar> from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat_set.c
A    i.landsat.toar\local_proto.h
A    i.landsat.toar\main.c
A    i.landsat.toar\description.html
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat.c
Compiling <i.landsat.toar>...
A    i.landsat.toar\earth_sun.c
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat.h
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat_met.c
A    i.landsat.toar\Makefile
A    i.landsat.toar\earth_sun.h
U   i.landsat.toar
Checked out revision 48242.
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/include/grass
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/bin
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/etc
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/driver
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/driver/db
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/fonts
test -d OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32 || mkdir -p OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32
C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Module.make:25: warning:
overriding commands for target `install'
C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Rules.make:90: warning:
ignoring old commands for target `install'
gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such
file or directory
make: *** [OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/earth_sun.o] Error 1
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
gcc -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/bin/include -IE:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/include -I/c/OSGeo4W/include -g -O2  -I/c/OSGeo4W/include     -DPACKAGE=\""grassmods"\"  -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/bin/include -IE:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/dist/include -o OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/earth_sun.o -c earth_sun.c
rm: cannot remove directory `E:\\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Warren_
18Nov10/.tmp/5676.0/i.landsat.toar': Permission denied
(Mon Sep 12 08:01:25 2011) Command finished (13 sec)
```

---

Still no joy, 
GRASS 6.4.2svn48674

```
g.extension -s -u --verbose extension=i.landsat.toar prefix=C:\OSGeo4W\GRASS64SVN\bin
which: wget: unknown command
Using CURL for downloading data.
Fetching <i.landsat.toar> from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat_set.c
A    i.landsat.toar\local_proto.h
A    i.landsat.toar\main.c
A    i.landsat.toar\description.html
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat.c
A    i.landsat.toar\earth_sun.c
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat.h
A    i.landsat.toar\landsat_met.c
A    i.landsat.toar\Makefile
A    i.landsat.toar\earth_sun.h
Compiling <i.landsat.toar>...
C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Grass.make:422: warning:
overriding commands for target `E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narra
ndera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/bin'
C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Grass.make:413: warning:
ignoring old commands for target `E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Nar
randera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/bin'
C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Module.make:25: warning:
overriding commands for target `install'
C:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include/Make/Rules.make:90: warning:
ignoring old commands for target `install'
 U   i.landsat.toar
Checked out revision 48683.
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/bin
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/include/grass
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/etc
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/driver
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/driver/db
mkdir -p E:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/fonts
test -d OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32 || mkdir -p OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32
gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such
file or directory
make: *** [OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/earth_sun.o] Error 1
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
gcc -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include -IE:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/include -I/c/OSGeo4W/include -g -O2  -I/c/OSGeo4W/include     -DPACKAGE=\""grassmods"\"  -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include -IC:/OSGeo4W/GRASS64SVN/include -IE:\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrandera_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/include -o OBJ.i686-pc-mingw32/earth_sun.o -c earth_sun.c
rm: cannot remove directory `E:\\GRASSDATA/QG_UTM55S/Narrand
era_20110918/.tmp/4948.0/i.landsat.toar': Permission denied
(Sun Oct 09 16:18:33 2011) Command finished (11 sec)
```

Comment: Did you run g.extension from the wxGUI menu? From the messages it appears that the mingW installation is not functional.

Comment: You can have a fresh snapshot winGRASS version from here: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/

Comment: Hi Markus, no joy on this. tried 47493 from today. Windows can find g.extension.py

Comment: Hi Bill: "Windows can find g.extension.py"... but? please explain a bit more.

Comment: Sorry, my typo error,     windows can't find g.extension.py   there is a new dialog which opens but you have to go into the older dialog to specify the extension of interest, and when you execute this it goes the to error dialog.

Comment: I am quite happy on GRASS 7 on windows.....

Answer (score 3):

We (GRASS Team) are planning to precompile all GRASS Addons for winGRASS on our http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/ server and to simply deliver executables via g.extension for Windows. This will facilitate things for the end user. Coming soon!

Comment: Now it is available! From GRASS 6.4.2RC3 onwards the new Addons installer is available. Preview at wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64

Comment: I could not install the self installer, it failed on some dll. I will look more at this first.

Comment: Which dll precisely?

Comment: I took the latest svn, installed OK.   Ran the module addon installer, appeared to run fine and completed the install of 3 addons including i.landsat.toar. But they did not appear in the menus.    In any case I tried to load up a Landsat image, but it won't display in this svn. Am exploring that issue first.

Comment: I also realized that it does not appear in the menu. Will investigate with the developer.